# How to create an ontology from raw data (CSV)?

Tags: rdf, data-modeling, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I am modelling university data using an OWL ontology with relevant classes, object properties, etc. I have the university data lying in a simple text file (say CSV). I want to create ontologies using my model for these data.  My questions are:

1. Is this how ontologies work?
2. If so, how can this be done using using Jena?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood your question, you have an ontology that represents a university model and you want to create owl instances using the data set which is in the form of CSV. Please correct me if you need something else.

The answer to your first question is Yes.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. CSV data can be converted to RDF using available libraries with the help of Jena. here is the link [link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/ConverterToRdf) ;
   And here is the more detailed answer :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373425/populate-an-existing-ontology-from-a-csv-file-using-jena)
2. This can also be done using XSLT, write an xsl to convert the data from csv to owl individuals. And append those owl individuals to ontology using OWL API.
3. If you are using Protege to build the ontologies, Protege provides a plugin to import CSV data. [Link](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Excel_Import)
4. There are few other ways also.

All the above 3 approaches are used by many people and there is no one particular standard for solving this problem. You can choose an approach as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much Swamy. You've understood my question correctly.  

I use Protege for modelling but the plugin you've mentioned is deprecated. I'll check if there is an alternative plugin.  

I really find the 2nd option to be effective - though it requires some effort.

Comment: I am glad to know that you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to ontology, I recommend starting with some user-friendly existing tools first. Once you become familiar with ontology concepts and how it works, you can proceed to write your own code using open-source tools like Jena to create an ontology from CSV data.
If you're interested, there's a cloud-based web service developed by a Ph.D. student at ENSAM ParisTech France. Here's the its link github:
https://github.com/zzheng90/csv2rdf-converter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).